# Rename Files to include a suffix based on the previous business day

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have a group of files in a directory. The file names stay the same, but the contents of each file is updated daily and the files have different extensions` (.pptx, .xlsx, .xlsm). After the files are updated each day, I want to rename them to include a string that is dependent on the previous business weekday (_MON, _TUE, _WED, _THU, _FRI). The suffix should be after the original file name and before the file extension. The format I'm looking for is filename.dayofweeksuffix.fileextension. I was able to accomplish this with the code below, but it seems clunky and repetitive and I know there must be a simpler way to accomplish the task. I've been working in IT for many years, but I'm a total beginner to python and would appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide. My code is below for Monday, which adds a _FRI to all of the file names. The block of code below is repeated in my python file for Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday and it seems unnecessarily long and repetitive.

My thought is that I can create variables for the file path and the the file names and then join them together in the os.rename function. The part I am struggling with is how to make the previous weekday suffix dynamic based on the current day of the week.

I created a tuple with the suffixes that I want to select from.

```
weekday_tuple = ("_MON","_TUE","_WED","_THU","_FRI","_SAT","_SUN")
```

But I'm not sure how to select the suffix for the previous weekday from the tuple dynamically based on the current day of the week.

Thanks

```
import datetime
import os
import shutil as sl

datetime.datetime.today().weekday()

if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 0:

os.rename("my file path\\my file 1 name.pptx", "my new file path\\my new file 1 name_FRI.pptx")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 2 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 2 name_FRI.xlsx")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 3 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 3 name_FRI.xlsx")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 4 name.xlsm", "my new file path\\my new file 4 name_FRI.xlsm")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 5 name.xlsm", "my new file path\\my new file 5 name_FRI.xlsm")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 6 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 6 name_FRI.xlsx")
 
os.rename("my file path\\my file 7 name.xlsm", "my new file path\\my new file 7 name_FRI.xlsm")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 8 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 8 name_FRI.xlsx")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 9 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 9 name_FRI.xlsx")

os.rename("my file path\\my file 10 name.xlsx", "my new file path\\my new file 10 name_FRI.xlsx")

#code repeats for the other 4 business days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something but why not use yesterday's date? Then you just concat your path name with this.

```py
import datetime
import os


weekday_tuple = ("_MON","_TUE","_WED","_THU","_FRI","_SAT","_SUN")

yesterday = weekday_tuple[(datetime.datetime.today()- datetime.timedelta(days=1)).weekday()]

os.rename("my_file_name.pptx", "my_new_file_name"+yesterday+".pptx")
```

Note: You have some indentation problems in your code, also, I'm unsure what your `if` case should do so my answer applies to your written question. The rest is just looping for the files in your folder and moving them (using whatever, `os.listdir` or `os.walk`).

EDIT 2.2.
If you do not wish to have Sunday and Saturday there, one simple fix is to replace them by Friday in the dict, the rest remains the same.

```
weekday_tuple = ("_MON","_TUE","_WED","_THU","_FRI","_FRI","_FRI")
```

Maybe if you elaborated more (are the data being moved during weekend, ie., can you ever `6` and `5` for `yesterday`? If not, you could just use a dict as proposed by @serrobit and drop those. But this solution is more robust to when you do your moving and does not cost anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The previous day needs to be the previous business day does not include weekend days. It's Monday through Friday only. So on Monday, the file suffix would need to be _FRI.

Comment: In that case you have easy 2 optiions, 1. change the dict, 2. check it manually. I have updated my answer using 1.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary

```
EXTENSIONS =  {0: '_FRI', 1: '_FRI', 2: '_MON', 3: '_TUE', 4: '_WED', 5: '_THU', 6: '_FRI'}
```

Then for your files

```
files = ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsm", "file3.pptx"]
new_filenames = { old_filename : f"{old_filename.split('.')[0]}{EXTENSIONS[datetime.datetime.today().day]}.{old_filename.split('.')[1]}" for old_filename in files}
```

Since today is Monday, this should yield for `new_filenames`:

```
{'file1.xlsx': 'file1_SUN.xlsx', 'file2.xlsm': 'file2_SUN.xlsm', 'file3.pptx': 'file3_SUN.pptx'}
```

Then just iterate over the items of `new_filenames`:

```
for old, new in new_filenames.items():
        os.rename(old,new)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I like the idea of creating a dictionary and using the for command, but the previous day needs to be the previous business day does not include weekend days. It's Monday through Friday only.

Comment: So on Monday, the file suffix would need to be _FRI.

Comment: Okay, then we just need to change the mapping for 0 and 1 to "_FRI" in EXTENSIONS. That way files for Monday, Sunday and Saturday all get renamed with "_FRI" ( indices 1, 0, and 6 respectively). I'll go ahead and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note here is that [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) has the format specification `%a` for (abbreviated) day names:

```py
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

filepath = (now - day).strftime("/path/to/file_%a")

print(filepath)  # /path/to/file_Mon
```